# Android ScoreNinja show scores only

Tags: android

I d like to show the global scores with scoreninja, and i dont like to ask for a name. How can i do this? (only show the scores, nothing else)

Leslie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private ScoreNinjaAdapter scoreNinjaAdapter;
scoreNinjaAdapter.show(-1);
```

Comment: this is an empty alertdialog, with null item, why?

Comment: Just to double check, have you try inserting records to the high score board?